# I want to show only the decimal places "Truncate floats without rounding"

Tags: python, decimal

My code has shown well up to the second decimal place so far.

> res4 = Decimal('%.2f' % (res4 * 100 / 100))

but i got problem

> 35.3169 --> 35.32

Why is it being raised?
I want to throw everything away from the third decimal place.
And if there is no second decimal place, I want to make 0.
help bro!!!

I don't think it's the way I find it.

```
def truncate_number(num, limit):
  int_part, fract_part = str(Decimal(num)).split('.')
  return Decimal(f'{int_part}.{fract_part[:limit]}')

[input] truncate_number(35.3169, 2)
[output] 35.31
[input] truncate_number(31.1, 2)
[output] 31.10
[input] truncate_number(31.4, 2)
[output] 31.39
[input] truncate_number(31.5, 2)
[output] 31.5
[input] truncate_number(30.22, 2)
[output] 30.21
```

what happen...
I want to look up to second the minority.
I want to throw away the third digit.
And if there is no second decimal place, I want to make 0.

************* I think I need to use this. ************

```
res4 = math.floor(res4 * 1000) / 100
res4_2f='%.2f' % (res4 / 10)
[input] 40.41
[output] 40.41
```

tell me advise!

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Show your code as [mre], as well as full traceback you get.

Comment: By "error" you just mean *"unexpected result"*?

Comment: yeah unexpected!

Comment: Check my answer please. And I think you should rename your question to make it more informative. I'd rename it to something like "Truncate floats without rounding"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to round numbers, you can truncate floats with string operations like this:

```
def truncate_number(num, limit):
  int_part, fract_part = str(float(num)).split('.')
  return float(f'{int_part}.{fract_part[:limit]}')

In [9]: truncate_number(35.3169, 2)
Out[9]: 35.31

In [9]: truncate_number(1.1199, 2)
Out[9]: 1.11

In [11]: truncate_number(1.1199, 3)
Out[11]: 1.119

In [11]: truncate_number(-1.1199, 3)
Out[11]: -1.119
```

Keep in mind that this function wont convert `1` to `1.000`:

```
In [13]: truncate_number(1, 3)
Out[13]: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing a Decimal from a string. The format specifier you're using will round the value. For example:

```
print('%.2f' % 35.3169)
```

...will emit 35.32